# Why is my DIV anchor link larger than the image set?

Tags: html, css

So I have a delete and like button, I have moved them to a DIV tag, Here is an image:

So, I have set the width and height of the div tags to the EXACT size of the image, yet it still shows UNDER the "Like" button, also, The link goes past the image (like the "like" button is 42px width, but its actually like a 90px link) and it is the same with the delete button, I Don't understand why.

```
.delete {
    background:url(../images/default/boxes/2/delete.png) no-repeat;
    width:17px;
    height:17px;

}
.like {
    background:url(../images/default/boxes/2/like.png) no-repeat;
    width:42px;
    height:17px;

}
```

I'm sorry if I Do not explain very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display:inline-block`, if you placed them inside divs they are just block elements that end up on different rows.

Comment: So simple and So silly, Sorry, And thank you! This is the first thing I should have done. I'm not thinking today :( had very little sleep due to my new born. Thank you buddy!

Comment: I will Accept but can't for 4 mins!